# Connecting two nodes in tree rectangular

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, tikz-qtree

I want to draw a tree like this:

[image: tree with nodes connected]

The closest I could get to this was the following code:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{tikz-qtree}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{level 1+/.style={level distance=2\baselineskip}}
\Tree[.IP NP
       [.VP [.\node(v){V}; [ \node(v1){}; ] ]
            NP 
            [.PP [.\node(p){P}; \node(p1){}; ]
                 NP ] 
       ]
]
\draw (v) -- (v1) -- (p1) -- (p);
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

But this involves empty auxiliary nodes and the lines have some space in the middle. Is there a simpler way to do this? Are there options to `\draw`that can do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the orthogonal intersection node and a little manual shift.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{level 1+/.style={level distance=2\baselineskip}}
\Tree[.IP NP
       [.VP [.\node(v){V};]
            NP 
            [.PP [.\node(p){P};]
                 NP ] 
       ]
]
\draw (v) |-  ([yshift=-5mm]v |- p) -| (p);
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! What does the manual shift do? Does it shift a `v |- p`object?

Comment: @StefanMüller It finds the orthogonal intersection (going down from `v` vertically and going to `p` horizontally. Then shifts 5mm down.