# How to converge various nodes with rectangular shapes and arrow in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, arrows, tikz-trees

I'm very new to TikZ. I would like to join some nodes as shown in the attached image

[image]

I've got some idea from this thread [tree rectangular](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85189/connecting-two-nodes-in-tree-rectangular). However, I could not manage to implement this properly with the arrow. I would appreciate if you share your comments/suggestion to implement this.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing what you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have. See [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Comment: @Jubobs thanks for your comment. Actually, I could only produced the three nodes at the left column, so was not sure if that'll be useful to show or not. But I got your point and I'll try to put my question with a MWE.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Complicate the coding to make it easier to understand.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\tikzset{
    block/.style = {draw,rectangle,minimum size=1cm,rounded corners = 1ex,thick}}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
%% first column
\node [block,draw=blue] (1a) {};
\node [block,draw=blue,below = 1cm of 1a] (1b) {};
\node [block,draw=blue,below = 1cm of 1b] (1c) {};
%% second column
\node [block,draw=green!70!blue,below right = 0cm and 2cm of 1a] (2a) {};
\node [block,draw=green!70!blue,below = 1cm of 2a] (2b) {};
%% paths
\draw[thick,magenta] (1a.-20) -| ([xshift=-1cm]2a.west)coordinate (a);
\draw[thick,magenta] (a) |- (1b.20);
\draw[thick,blue!60!green,-latex] (a) |- (2a.west);
\draw[thick,magenta] (1b.-20) -| ([xshift=-1cm]2b.west)coordinate (b);
\draw[thick,magenta] (b) |- (1c.20);
\draw[thick,blue!60!green,-latex] (b) |- (2b.west);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for your reply. I could implement this in my code now. I was wondering if you are aware of any tutorial/site on TikZ for the beginners.

Comment: @rana Go to `texexample.net`. You can use those to learn new stuff. :D

Comment: @rana: `pgfmanual` is the best resource. `texdoc pgfmanual` from command line/prompt.

Answer (score 2):

An other alternative via matrix node from TiKZ

[image]

Code:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,positioning,scopes}

    \begin{document}
    \tikzset{%
    line/.style={draw, thick},
    point/.style={coordinate},
    boxes/.style={draw, rectangle,
                thick,minimum height=2cm, rounded corners,
                minimum width=1cm, text=black, thick,
                text width=25mm,  align=center}
}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
    % Place nodes
    \matrix[column sep=1cm, row sep=0.5cm]{
    \node [boxes,blue] (1a){}; &                    &                             \\
                               & \node[point](d){}  &\node[boxes,green] (3a){};   \\  
    \node [boxes,blue] (1b){}; &                    &                             \\
                               & \node[point](e){}; &\node[boxes,green] (3b){};   \\
    \node [boxes,blue] (1c){}; &                    &                             \\
    }; 
    % Draw edges
    \path [line,magenta] ([shift={(0cm,-0.3cm)}]1a.east) -| (d) |- ([shift={(0cm,0.3cm)}]1b.east) ;
    \path [line, -latex',blue!60!green] (d.east) -- (3a.west);
    \path[line,magenta] ([shift={(0cm,-0.3cm)}]1b.east) -| (e) |- ([shift={(0cm,0.3cm)}]1c.east);
    \path [line, -latex',blue!60!green] (e.east) -- (3b.west);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. I was not aware of this more structured format.